# Numbers that have two or more prime factors

Tags: primes, prime-factoring, greatest-common-divisor

```
def fun(n) :    
    ans = 0
    for i in range(1,n) :
        for j in range(i+1,n+1) :
            ans += gcd(i,j)
```

This is the actual function to be calculated when n is given. The upper bound for n will be 1e6 and the time limit will be 2 seconds. Directly using the above function will clearly exceed the Time Limit. So, I've come up with a following solution. It works for small cases, but failing to pass when N>=100.
Here is the c++ code :

```
    # include <cstdio>
    # include <bits/stdc++.h>
    # include <cstring>
    # include <cstdlib>
    # include <cctype>
    # include <string>
    # include <cfloat>
    # include <cmath>
    # include <iostream>
    # include <fstream>
    # include <cassert>
    # include <iterator>
    # include <vector>
    # include <queue>
    # include <map>
    # include <algorithm>
    # include <set>
    # include <sstream>
    # include <stack>
    # include <cassert>

    # define MEM(a,b,s) memset(a,(b),s)
    # define MAX(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
    # define MIN(a,b) ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))
    # define MP make_pair
    # define pb push_back
    # define inf 1000000000
    # define MOD 1000000007
    # define SZ 1000001
    # define lli long long int
    # define li long int  
    # define repeat(i,a) for(lli i=1;i<a;i++)
    # define repeat_untill(a) while (a)
    # define repeat2(i,j,k) for (j=i+1;j<=k;j++)
    # define ch char
    # define gi(a) readFast<int>(&a)
    # define gl(a) readFast<li>(&a)
    # define gll(a) readFast<lli>(&a)

    using namespace std;

    template <class fast_io>
    inline fast_io readFast(fast_io *a)
    {
            char c=0;
            int sign=0;
            while(c<33 && c!='-')
                    c=getchar_unlocked();
            *a=0;
            if (c=='-')
            {
                    sign=1;
                    c=getchar_unlocked();
            }
            while(c>33)
            {
                    *a=*a*10+(c-48);
                    c=getchar_unlocked();
            }
            if (sign==1)
                    return -*a;
            else
                    return *a;
    }       

    int prime[100001];

    void sieve()
    {
            MEM(prime,0,100001);
            for (int i=2;i<100001;i++)
            {
                    if (!prime[i])
                    {
                            lli j=2;
                            while (i*j < 100001)
                            {
                                    prime[i*j] = 1;
                                    j += 1;
                            }
                    }
            }
    }

    lli gcd(lli a,lli b)
    {
            return (b==0?a:gcd(b,a%b));
    }

    int main(void)
    {
            lli n;
            sieve();
            gll(n);
            repeat_untill(n)
            {
                    lli i , j , ans =0;
                    repeat(i,n)
                    {
                            lli divs,coprimes=0;
                            if (n%i == 0)
                            {
                                    divs = (n/i)-1;
                                    coprimes = (n-i)-divs;
                                    ans += ((divs*i)+coprimes);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    lli k = (int)(pow(i,0.5)),m=2,totdiv=0;
                                    if (k*k < i)
                                            k += 1;
                                    while (m<=k)
                                    {
                                            if (!prime[m])
                                            {
                                                    divs = (n-i)/m;
                                                    totdiv += divs;
                                                    ans += ((divs*m));

                                            }
                                            m += 1;
                                    }       
                                    ans += (n-i-totdiv);
                            }
                    }
                    cout<<ans<<endl;
                    gll(n);
            }
            return (0);
    }
```

The problem here is if there will be n-i such that it has two prime factors, then this algo will fail as for a value i each j greater than i and lesser than n will only be taken into account for gcd calculation once. For example if n-i will be 25 then prime factors that it has will be 2,3,5. Here 15 will be considered twice at 3 and 5. Kindly help how can i eliminate the 15 after performing the action with 3.

Or is there any other approach to calculate the function fun(n) faster below O(n^2)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just now found that there is a solution with Euler-Totient function exists.

Comment: Your code suffers from a severe case of the [Sieve of Smith](http://zsmith.co/primes.html) syndrome - premature optimisation of irrelevant (utterly insignificant) parts of the code. If you told us what the actual problem/task is then we could give you specific advice; barring that it can only be said that optimisations of any kind are usually neither necessary nor helpful in solving programming challenges of the SPOJ type. What's necessary is **analysing the problem**. Half-assed solutions can sometimes scrape through with heavy optimisation but correct solutions need only simple, clean code.